# how much money can immigrant family carry to USA?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, money

Hi I am Libyan I have US IR1 visa to the USA .
family of six members 
 adults and 4 kids 
 how much Maximum money as immigrant family can carry to USA ?
please advise

Comment: You had the tags [tag:canada] and [tag:transit] which didn't seem relevant to your question as you wrote it, so I removed them.  If they were, then please edit your question to add details.

Comment: Also, a caution: the word "immigrant" suggests that you are planning to live in the US permanently, which is not allowed on a B-2 visa.

Comment: It is a very expatriate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is as much money as you have. Amounts over $10,000 in cash or other negotiable instruments (e.g., checks) *must* be declared to the Border officials on arrival. (This is equally true of USA citizens.) The limit is for the family, not per person. If you are transiting in Canada, they have a similar rule. You will need a transit visa, and you must declare amounts over $(CDN)10,000, also per family.

As @Nate-Eldredge points out, a B-2 visa is not for immigration. Arriving with very large amounts of cash will make the border guards even more suspicious of your intentions, above the [existing difficulties](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/26/world/americas/trump-travel-ban-effects.html) for Libyan nationals.

Carrying large amounts of cash is an invitation to disaster, through theft or even accidental loss. I urge you to bring a reasonable amount for your trip but to arrange some sort of bank transfer if you intend to move large sums to the USA, whether temporarily or permanently.

Comment: the question states that it is a IR-1 visa, not a B visa